# Ruby on rails has many through on a concern using a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I have a problem with using has_many through on a concern and from a polymorphic association.

So I have 3 models and concern here:
https://gist.github.com/andreorvalho/5c2f0e3800fbb126df85

my problem is when I create a competition and do:

competition.content_permission_sources I get all the correct values, but when I do
competition. permission_sources I get an empty collection proxy, even though the content_permission_source has a permission_source:

```
2.1.1 :022 > c.content_permission_sources
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ContentPermissionSource id: 1, permissible_id: 1, permissible_type: "Competition", permission_source_id: 5, is_forced: nil, created_at: "2014-05-26 19:08:40", updated_at: "2014-05-26 19:08:40">, #<ContentPermissionSource id: 2, permissible_id: 1, permissible_type: "Competition", permission_source_id: 4, is_forced: nil, created_at: "2014-05-26 19:08:40", updated_at: "2014-05-26 19:08:40">, #<ContentPermissionSource id: 3, permissible_id: 1, permissible_type: "Competition", permission_source_id: 6, is_forced: nil, created_at: "2014-05-26 19:08:40", updated_at: "2014-05-26 19:08:40">]> 
2.1.1 :023 > c.permission_sources
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 
2.1.1 :024 > c.content_permission_sources.first.permission_source
 => #<PermissionSource id: 5, collectable_id: 1, collectable_type: "Site", source_code: 690089, source_name: "fallback", permission_type: "newsletter", country_code: "dk", created_at: "2014-05-26 19:03:01", updated_at: "2014-05-26 19:03:01">
```

Anybody has an idea of what I am doing wrong and how can I make sure I can access it correctly?

Comment: Try and output the sql of these queries with `.to_sql` at the end of your lines, show us the result.

Comment: well it seems that the object needs to be reloaded as there is some caching on my queries. I have tried to create an object and without querying before its created and after I got values on c.permission_sources. Do you know what could be doing this caching? because if I do c.reload and then c. permission_sources then it works fine

Comment: Once you run a query, it is cached

Comment: so what happens is: c.permission_sources before being saved returns empty, after I save it it returns empty as well, even though it's not. if I do reload then it shows the correct values, shouldn't this reload happen automatically?